# Создание XML с помощью c#

Tags: c#, xml

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно создать xml-файл по средствам языка c#. Вот мой код создания xml-файла.

```
String str = "D:\\file.xml";
XmlTextWriter textWritter = new XmlTextWriter(str, Encoding.UTF8);
textWritter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
textWritter.WriteStartDocument();

textWritter.WriteStartElement("NAME");
textWritter.WriteString(TextBox1.Text);
textWritter.WriteEndElement();
textWritter.Close();
```

Но мне нужно создать несколько тегов на одном уровне. Так как каждый будет отвечать за 1 поле. Как в моём случае `NAME`. Но создать несколько тегов старт элементом оказалось нельзя. Как можно сделать то же самое только с несколькими полями. Вот как выглядит сейчас мой xml-файл.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно что бы выглядел примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть мне нужны поля на 1 уровне в xml. Как это можно реализовать? Если можно в примере покажите мой код с исправлениями которые мне нужно сделать.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61661/discussion-on-question-by---xml---c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как насчет использовать прелести [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Опишите вашу модель:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

И после серилизуйте ее:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, person); 
string xml = stringWriter.ToString();
```

Сохранить на компьютер можно простым [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, xml);
```

[Проверить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xbUIQL)!

Comment: Советую все такие штуки которые имеют атрибуты, как XmlSerializer, использовать явно, то есть указывать что надо сериализовать,а что не надо. Но это по желанию, допустим если модель не имеет каких то "ненужных" при сериализации полей, то не стоит.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda что вы имеете в виду? `XmlSerializer` - не атрибут. Если вы подразумевали атрибут `XmlElement` - то все равно все поля будут серилизоваться, которые не помечены атрибутом `XmlIgnore`. Если не надо явно задавать имя поля при серилизации/десерилизации - то помечать атрибутом `XmlElement` - бесполезное занятие.

Comment: @AGS17 Включу экстрасенса, скорее всего он имел ввиду [Serialize], чтобы явно указать что класс сериализуем, ещё бы атрибуты к полям явно указать - было бы вообще идеально)

Comment: @AGS17 а как вашим способом сохранить эту xml на компьютер? Мне же не просто нужно вывести на экран. Просто у переменной xml почему то нет свойства save. Спасибо за ответ заранее.

Comment: @Андрей может потому что `xml` - переменная типа `string`? Обновил ответ.

Comment: @AGS17 извините, забыл отписать. Я уже нашёл этот метод. Осталось только разобраться как убрать длинную строчку лишнего текста который появляется после корневого элемента. Вы не подскажите как его убрать? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: @Андрей вы про `xmlns:xsd` и т.д? Зачем вам ее убирать?

Comment: @AGS17 да про неё. Потому что мне не нужно это. Мне потом нужно парсить xml-ку и лишний текст уж точно не понадобиться.

Answer (score 7):

Вы пытаетесь создать невалидный xml. В корректном xml-файле должен быть корневой элемент а также много других достаточно очевидных правил. Если у вас есть сомнения, что вам xml допустим, то вы можете проверить его на каком-нибудь специальном сайте, например:

[XML Validator](https://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidator)

---

Еще один способ создания xml - использовать `Linq2Xml`.

Если взять класс из ответа @AGS17 :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

то метод для получения xml будет следующим

```
public static XElement CreateXML(Person person)
{
    return new XElement(
        "person",
            new XElement("Name", person.Name),
            new XElement("Surname", person.Surname),
            new XElement("Age", person.Age));
}
```

Пример использования

```
var xml = CreateXML(new Person { Name = "Сергей", Age = 30, Surname = "Петров" });
xml.Save(path);
```

В результате будет получен такой xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<person>
  <Name>Сергей</Name>
  <Surname>Петров</Surname>
  <Age>30</Age>
</person>
```

Comment: вы наверно имели в виду `var xml = Person.CreateXML(new Person { Name = "Сергей", Age = 30, Surname = "Петров" });` Потому что просто без класса метод не вызывается. По крайней мере у меня ошибка.

Comment: @Андрей да, это статический метод, его можно определить либо в классе `Person` либо в отдельном классе